# How to download rpm packages manually (without yum)?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I need to download .rpm packages into Windows for some reason. So I cannot use yum for downloading. Virtual machine option is not available either.

Can I download .rpm packages manually? If yes, what should I do? Dependency issue should be solved also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your dependencies issues you an use `yum deplist [package]`. That will return you a list for the package you listed in the commandline.

You can easily download the rpms once you know the mirrors you got them from if you are up-to-date. Because packages are overwritten regularly with new ones.

If you use CentOS you probably use EPEL repo (confirm with `yum repolist`). In that case you can browse : https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/ or https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7Server/x86_64/Packages/ depending on your version.

If it's from a custom repo, you can check in `/etc/yum.repos.d/your_repo.conf` and look for the line baseurl. You might find something like :
`baseurl=http://custom.repo.example.com/pub/7/$basearch`
In that case you have to change $basearch by x86_64 most probably. You might also have to change 7 to something else. And you'll be able to access it from any browser (you should go in the Packages directory once there).

Yum repos are basically just served by webservers, so you can browse them easily and find the packages you need.

---

If you happen to be out-of-date there might be a change that you have a local copy of the package you installed in your yum cache. Run `find /var/cache/yum/ -name "your_package_name*.rpm"` and cross fingers that it returns something interesting.

You could copy it from there and transfer it to your Windows machine, using any way you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** This answers only the download/extract on Windows, not dependency management. Add `repodata/repomd.xml` to the repository's base url and then examine `repomd.xml` to locate and download its `primary.xml` file which lists the urls to download desired `.rpm` file(s).  The script [`rpm2cpio.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/master/scripts/rpm2cpio.sh) can extract the (compressed) `cpio` archive which `cpio -id` can then copy into the filesystem.

First, find the base url for the repository; e.g.
`https://brave-browser-rpm-beta.s3.brave.com/x86_64/`

Add `repodata/repomd.xml` to find the repository metadata; e.g.
[`https://brave-browser-rpm-beta.s3.brave.com/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml`](https://brave-browser-rpm-beta.s3.brave.com/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml)

Examine `repomd.xml` to find the repository's `primary.xml` file; e.g. `repodata/2635976bb02dab08a696dbaad778feea3f3351a3238fb6f77af52c651dd931cd-primary.xml.gz`

Download `primary.xml` for the repository; e.g.

```
curl --output primary.xml.gz https://brave-browser-rpm-beta.s3.brave.com/x86_64/repodata/2635976bb02dab08a696dbaad778feea3f3351a3238fb6f77af52c651dd931cd-primary.xml.gz
gunzip primary.xml.gz
```

or use another download tool. Uncompress the file if it's compressed.

Examine `primary.xml` to locate the the desired `.rpm` archive.

```
grep location primary.xml
```

or perhaps

```
findstr "location" primary.xml
```

Download the desired `.rpm` file(s); e.g.

```
curl -O https://brave-browser-rpm-beta.s3.brave.com/x86_64/brave-browser-beta-0.67.99-1.x86_64.rpm
```

To unpack the contents from the `.rpm` file, here are some suggested utilities. Install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) to run the [`rpm2cpio.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/master/scripts/rpm2cpio.sh) script which extracts the `cpio` archive (probably compressed) from the `.rpm` file. (Use Cygwin's `setup-x86_64.exe` to install any script dependencies if necessary). Example:

```
rpm2cpio.sh brave-browser-beta-0.67.99-1.x86_64.rpm > payload
```

Install `cpio` and `gunzip`, `xz`, or `bunzip` using Cygwin's `setup-x86_64.exe` depending on how the `cpio` archive is packed. Figure out the format of the payload:

```
file payload
```

Now uncompress and then extract the `cpio` archive (An XZ compressed cpio archive in this example):

```
xz -d payload
cpio -id payload
```

Edit: [alien](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alien-pkg-convert/) is a much more versatile package format converter than rpm2cpio.sh. It's written in Perl. Also note that while this handles downloading and extracting RPMs on Windows (with Cygwin), it doesn't handle dependency management.