# Download yum package from third party repo without superuser privileges

Tags: centos, sudo, yum, rpm

### Context

I'm working on a Centos 7.9 remote machine where I need to install several packages, most of them available via yum. Unfortunately, my user does not have sudo or root privileges so I cannot use `yum install`.

As a workaround, I created a custom directory for downloading and installing packages via `yuminstaller`, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52567731/370798), using [user-yum.sh](https://gitlab.com/caroff/user-yum.sh).

### My problem

I need to install a package from a third party repo [(intel-hpckit)](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/installing-intel-oneapi-toolkits-via-yum.html#instruct).

### What I have tried

First, since I couldn't edit `/etc/yum.repos.d`, I created my own `yum.repos.d` directory under `user-yum.sh`'s `root/etc/` directory. Even after that, `yumdownloader` couldn't locate the package.

After that, I manually downloaded the `intel-hpckit-2021.2.0-2997.x86_64.rpm` file via `wget`, as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528746/163855).

Unfortunately, **this approach downloads only the specified package and not all of its required dependencies** (`intel-oneapi-compiler-fortran`, `intel-basekit`, `intel-oneapi-common-vars`, ...), so for `intel-hpckit` to work I should manually download each of the required packages, and the required packages of those (and so on), recursively.

### My question

**Is there a way I can automatically download and install the required third party package** (`intel-hpckit`) **along with its dependencies?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [yum install in user home for non-admins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61283/yum-install-in-user-home-for-non-admins)

Comment: @GAD3R. Not really. As I said in my answer, I can download yum packages to a folder inside my user's home. What I have not been able to do yet is to install the third party package, because I need sudo to add it's repo.

Comment: Have you considered asking the server's administrator to install the software for you? If not, do so. If they refuse then you need to take that appropriately further

Comment: @roaima I have, but since he is too busy, he cannot process requests as fasts as usually I need them. My ideal case would be to depend less on him every time I need a new package.